# arrange data from columns to matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I have sets of data arranged like this:

```
X  Y  Z
x1 y1 z1
x1 y2 z2
x1 y3 z3
x2 y1 z4
x2 y2 z5
x2 y3 z6
```

which I need to arrange into a table like this:

```
   y1 y2 y3
x1 z1 z2 z3
x2 z4 z5 z6
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this with vba?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be a VBA solution? You could do it fairly easily with cell formulas...

You can get the unique `X` and `Y` values by using Data > Remove Duplicates, then arrange them as the table headings like you want.

[image: Layout]

Then use the following formulas to populate the `XY` column and the table's `Z` values:

[image: Formulas]

Namely, for the `XY` concatenation:

```
=CONCAT(A2,",",B2)
```

You can enter this in the first cell and use the [AutoFill handle](http://www.keynotesupport.com/excel-basics/excel-auto-fill-handle-numbers-dates.shtml) to populate the entire column.

For the table's `Z` values, we use the `XY` value as a lookup for `MATCH`, which returns the row of the matching `XY` value from the same concatenation of the table's header column/row.

```
  =INDIRECT(CONCAT("C", MATCH(CONCAT($F2,",",G$1),$D:$D,0)))
```

Enter this into the top left cell and again drag it to fill the table.

Note the dollar signs in the formula, that stops AutoFill from relatively adjusting those rows/columns, fixing them as they are the column/row headers.

If you really need a VBA solution, it would be doable but your biggest tasks will be

```
1. Making sure the row/column header values are unique, and looking up where they are for each new row.
2. Handling what happens when they aren't unique (if your data input allows this)
```

Otherwise, follow a similar logic to the above cell formulas!

Edit:

@Scott suggested an equivalent function for the main lookup table which works well. I've added more dollar signs so that AutoFill can be used

```
=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(CONCAT($F2,",",G$1),$D:$D,0))
```

Comment: 1. CONCAT is only available in Office 365 Excel and with the method you are using CONCATENATE() will work just fine, which is available in all Excel.  2. instead of a volatile INDIRECT use the much faster and non volatile INDEX().  `=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(CONCAT($F2,",",G$1),$D:$D,0))`

Comment: hi @ScottCraner, nice comment, I'm not that used to using cell formulas, I'm a VBA junkie! You've seen what was my first working example code, yours is a good optimisation :)

Comment: Just a quick note on the difference between CONCANTENATE and CONCAT.  CONCAT will do a range: `CONCAT(A1:A10)` while CONCATENATE concatenates a series of inputs: `CONCANTENATE($F2,",",G$1)`,  Then there's the new TEXTJOIN which will add the deliminator and concatenate a range, `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A10)` this will concatenate everything that has a value in A1:A10 with a `,` between them.

Comment: As far as volatile functions: They will calculate every time excel calculates regardless if the underlying data changes or not.  Non volatile on calculate when the underlying data changes.  Plus Index, since it does not convert to a text then back again save one whole calculation.

Comment: @Wolfie the function is part of a larger sub I use to manipulate the data and export the results as xy tables in text files. I'd prefer to avoid  intermediate calculations in cells, but maybe it's not the right approach in excel.

Comment: @mistertea, you can sure do this all in VBA... one hybrid approach would be to just make the above table and insert the formulas from a macro instead of manually :)